# Word for "animals, including humans"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Commonly, "animals" means "all animals, except humans". So is there a single word for "animals, including humans"?

Particularly, if you had a list of two choices, animal or human, what would you write as the heading?

Context: I'm building an input form for game designers to fill out about things you can encounter in a fantasy world. And one property of an encounter is whether it's an encounter with humans, animals, and possibly more categories to be determined later (e.g. spirits, monsters, undead?).

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context?

Comment: I'm building an input form for game designers to fill out about things you can encounter in a fantasy world. And one property of an encounter is whether it's an encounter with humans, animals, and possibly more categories to be determined later (e.g. spirits?).

Comment: See my answer. You could add spirits to the list of categories :)

Comment: It might be a good idea to edit your answer to include the context.

Comment: I think I've seen "fauna" and "creatures" used in similar contexts, but I'm not sure how strictly accurate that is.

Comment: Would spirits/monsters/undead be in a different category from animals/humans? Perhaps natural beings v. unnatural beings?

Comment: The input could be titled "type of", followed by "entity", "being", "living things", and "organism" might work.  Also "creations" and "life".    Perhaps words like "mammals", "animalia", or "the living".

Comment: Before we separated ourselves from the rest of nature, the simple answer would have been zwon (zoon), from the Greek which gives us zoology. We use in some terms so why not anothers. Much like we say bibliography (etymologically to write a book), or bible (biblia = "books") yet we don't say billion. peninsula (almost an island) yet we don't say insula. The mixing of numerous languages has made words no longer relate; that is throughout our language.

Comment: Aside from the biological terms, "subject" might work as a technical term: "encounter subject", "actor" and "entity" are also often used.

Comment: @empedocle: ah, the classic UX dilemma. Should you invent (or borrow from another language, or find as obscure jargon) the best term to represent what you mean, or should you actually try to communicate something using your headings ;-)

Comment: I think _animals_ does include humans. No one would argue that humans aren't mammals, in the kingdom Animalia. And there are other words for non-human animals that are understood to exclude humans (not counting metaphorical usage), such as _beasts_.

Comment: In order to include spirits, and on the assumption that all of the beings you might encounter in the fantasy world your building, perhaps you want to use the label "sentient beings".

Comment: Reminds me of a sign I once saw at the entrance to a farm: "Beware Children And Other Animals".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a tricky one because people differ in what they consider to be an animal. Not only that but a biological dictionary would give a different answer from an everyday dictionary.

Some would say that humans are distinct from animals. (creationists for example)

Some would say that humans are animals. (evolutionists for example)

Some don't include lizards as animals. Others don't include insects.

It depends whether you want a technical answer or not.

**Some suggestions**

**Technical**

chordates

animalia

eukaryotes

**Non-technical**

beings

creatures

etc.

Comment: +1 for creatures, though the other terms are a but technical I fear

Comment: Thanks for your +1 - I appreciate it Actually my own preference is for 'beings' which you may have missed. I don't think it's technical is it?

Comment: I have always wondered about this. Does "creatures" imply any association with the creationism school of thought? Often, I force myself to switch to "beings". Is "creatures" completely acceptable in a casual scientific discussion?

Comment: @Adnan I have never thought of the word "creature" having anything to do with creationism, other than some spelling similarities from probably linguistic roots.

Comment: In the context of a fantasy world, per the comment from @AnsisMalins on the question, I think "creatures" will imply animals and humans as well as other fantasy humanoids like elves, orcs, etc. If that is the intention, then "creatures" may well be the best possible term.

Comment: @Adnan "Beings" is way more broad than animals... beings definitely do include humans and animals, but would also include intelligent plants, energy-based life, etc.

Comment: Incidentally, I absolutely 100% believe evolution happened basically as the average scientist described, which does not change the fact that in casual speech, as opposed to biology papers, "animal" implies "animal other than human".

Comment: +1 for "beings". It fits fairly well for all the things, both real and fantasy, that OP mentioned, without really including anything else.

Comment: @S.Buda "Creature" does have its roots in the Latin word for create, but that world also means beget or give birth to--so it doesn't necessarily imply creationism.

Comment: *"Some don't include lizards as animals. Others don't include insects."* **Really?!!** I am shocked. Is it just lizards and insects or do other reptiles and arthropods qualify as.. err... whatever they think they are (plants?) as well. What about birds and amphibians and fish and crustaceans and mollusks and...? That's really depressing.

Comment: Will there be extraterrestrials in your game?   Would "critter" be too informal?  I've seen the term "Congresscritter" several times in the SF magazine "Analog".

Comment: Do you have a citation for "some don't include lizards"? I have never heard the word "animal" used in this context.

Comment: @MarchHo: I can confirm I have heard several (biologically uneducated) people use "animal" where they mean "mammal".

Comment: It's probably obvious to anyone who'd even consider using the technical terms, but "chordates" excludes invertebrate animals, and "eukaryotes" includes plants. As such, they're a curious mix of technical language with a decidedly *untechnical* interpretation of what "animals, including humans" means in the question ;-)

Comment: @MarchHo: definition 1.2 at https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/animal

Answer (score 26):

**Q: Is there a single word for "animals, including humans"?**

**A:** Humans *are* included in the Kingdom *Animalia*

> [**Animals**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal) are multicellular, eukaryotic organisms of the kingdom Animalia (also called Metazoa). All animals are motile, meaning they can move spontaneously and independently, at some point in their lives. Their body plan eventually becomes fixed as they develop, although some undergo a process of metamorphosis later on in their lives. All animals are heterotrophs: they must ingest other organisms or their products for sustenance. (Wikipedia, *Animalia*)

---

**Domain** *Eukarya* - **Kingdom** *Animalia* - **Phylum** *Chordata* - **Subphylum** *Vertebrata* - **Class** *Mammalia* - Order Primates - **Family** *Hominidae* - **Genus** *Homo* - **Species** *Sapien*

---

> [**Order Primates**](http://classic.sidwell.edu/us/science/vlb5/Labs/Classification_Lab/Eukarya/Animalia/Chordata/Vertebrata/Mammalia/Primates/)
>
> The primates belong to the class *Mammalia*. They show all of the normal features of mammals, including hair and mammary glands for nursing the young. They are endothermic, have vertebrae and a skeleton, and are segmented deuterosomes, with a coelom made from an outgrowth of the digestive tract. Primates are eutherians, meaning that they have a placenta that provides a more intimate relationship between mother and child while the mother nurses the child. Eutherians are also the mammals with the longest relationship between mother and young. The above features make the animals of the order Primates also eutherians, mammals, vertebrates, and chordates.
>
> There are 13 families in the order Primates.
>
> **Family** *Hominidae* - humans, chimpanzees, gorillas, orangutans
>
> http://classic.sidwell.edu/us/science/vlb5/Labs/Classification_Lab/Eukarya/Animalia/Chordata/Vertebrata/Mammalia/Primates/)

---

**Q:** **[I]f you had a list of two choices, animal or human, what would you write as the heading?**

**A:** If I had to choose between *Human* or *Animal*, my choice would be ***Animal***.

(My language choice is, admittedly, informed by philosophical, ethical and political concerns. I think that maintaining the conceit [embedded in our common language] that the distinctions which differentiate *Homo sapiens* from the other members of *Hominidae* are sufficient to justify an exclusive categorization, has lately been ... counterproductive.)

---

*Supplemental*: In the context of the categories involved with game development, perhaps **Human**, **Animal**, and **Life-form** or **Entity** (mortal and *non*-mortal).

Comment: Seen the [classification rap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XfIulmAuqk) from _Community_?

Comment: +1 , Vertebrate animals include humans. I had to do a "control F" to check if vertebrate is already a part of your answer and it is.  : )

Comment: -1 Although biologically correct this is showing a total and utter lack of understanding for the word 'animal' in common English language usage.

Comment: Thank you for the input @David Mulder, though you have drawn an errant conclusion as my answer is both knowing and intentional. Sometimes I arrive at an OP and find that my preferred answer has already been adequately presented by another user. If I feel I can post another perspective that might be useful I'll adapt. This answer is an example of that. ;-)

Comment: @LittleEva What extra perspective is given by providing a user with incorrect usage advice? :S I mean, if we would be on biology.SE or if the user would have given *any* indication that he was writing in a biological context this would have been valid, but in those situations the question wouldn't even have come up.

Comment: @David Mulder - in defense of the answer I provided I can only say that a number of users seem to have found it somewhat less than completely useless (until just a few moments ago it was tied for the most up-votes). I apologize if my answer was not helpful to you. I'm a work in progress.

Comment: Well, as this question made it to the HNQ-list and most users come from SO it stands to reason that a lot of those users will forget that language is about communication and not about technical definitions. I am just confused that a high-rep user from the english.SE community would forget such a thing. And yes, I know I am pretty harsh in my criticism, but as far as I can see this answer doesn't belong on english.SE at all as it's hardly about the English language at all.

Comment: English is my native language, and pretty much everyone I interact with on a regular basis (granted, I live in a University town) uses the word 'animal' in such a way that it would include 'human'. Frankly, I am surprised by the number of people here who are taking it for granted that 'animal' does not typically include humans even when used in casual context. That said, the OP does explicitly state this as an assumption, so a good answer should at least acknowledge that assumption. I personally could see using "animal" as the label, and "non-human animal" vs. "human" as options.

Comment: You're right, I've acted upon the suggestions. Thanks for pointing that out to me, @Ben Hocking

Answer (score 16):

In your case of a fantasy game, a common word for this category might be 'mortals'.

Comment: This excludes "immortal" creatures and people, which exist in fantasy settings.

Comment: Are plants excluded from this classification though? Most plants are not immortal.

Comment: @tarnu: from my own knowledge of fantasy settings, those would usually be classed "monsters" and/or "undead", mentioned as possible future directions in the questioner's scheme, so it's right that they are excluded from the category that this question seeks a name for. But it's true that if the questioner explicitly wants plant-based "things you encounter" to be excluded from this category, then calling it "mortals" rather than "animals" will backfire.

Answer (score 11):

Humans are a variety of living beings called **mammals**.  This puts us in the same category as mice, dogs, cats, cows, pigs, sheep, monkeys, and any other species that:

- is warm-blooded
- breathes air
- gives birth to live young
- suckles their young

(*mammal* comes from the same root word as *mammary*, which means a female breast capable of producing milk).

This leaves out bugs, spiders, snakes & lizards (reptiles), frogs, toads (amphibians), birds, fish, and other sea creatures (except dolphins and whales, which are mammals).

If you want to include *all* animals along with humans, you could say **living beings** (most people would not think this includes plants).

If you want to emphasize that humans can *think and feel*, you could group them only with those animals we consider to have some capacity for *thinking and feeling*, by saying **sentient beings**.  (There will be some dispute as to which species this includes.)

Comment: This a good, labor-intensive, and underappreciated answer Brian, +1

Comment: Don't forget that there are some [mammals that lay eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotreme).

Comment: I thought it would have to say, "and any *of the* other species that..." Did I mess up?

Comment: @Catija:  ah, yes, an exception to the rule.  Humans are so fond of putting things in tidy categories, but nature always has the last laugh.  Three cheers for the webfooted platypus and the spiny echidna!

Comment: @Mazura:  _species_ is both singular and plural.  One species, two species, this species, those species, other species, another species, any other species.  So my mistake was in using Plural "are" with _any other species_.  But yes, your suggestion would have fixed it as well.

Answer (score 8):

I'd personally just use "Fauna".  The phrase "Flora & Fauna" is commonly used terminology to refer to "Plants & Animals".

Comment: Yeah someone said Fauna. My faith is restored

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to differentiate between animals and humans, you could call the two categories *creatures* and *humans*. However, if you wanted to distinguish between animals (including humans) and other categories such as plants, it would be fine to label humans as animals. I say this because it is not uncommon to hear that all natural things fall into one of three categories: *animal*, *vegetable* or *mineral* (you could add further fantasy categories as required). And besides,  technically speaking, humans *are* animals.

Comment: Don't forget the word "Humanoid." Which I think fits the fantasy genre better than just humans as things such as goblins, orcs, elves, and dwarves would all be "humanoid."

Answer (score 4):

I find that it often helps to translate a word into another language (you can use Google translate if you do not speak the language) and get new ideas or input that way.  Other languages have a different way of describing something, and that can be helpful.

For example the German language has the word *Lebewesen*, a literal translation of which is: "living being." In the German language it is understood that this word describes anything that is "alive"; therefore, it includes humans, animals, plants, flowers, but not viruses. From that idea I realized that you could also call something a "breathing being," as both humans and animals do breathe, but that would exclude the plants because they do not breathe. But as someone else has accurately noted, both humans and animals do breathe as well as move, but plants usually do not move by their own choice and free will.

Google translates the German word *Lebewesen* with "creature," "living thing," "created entity," and "beast." Living organism is another translation that comes very close.

Beast is a bit of "weird" translation of the word because humans are only called beasts when they behave badly.  An animal can easily be called a beast, but plants or flowers are almost never called beasts. So that word leaves room for discussion.

A breathing being in french would be "*être respirer*."

The German language also uses the words *Zweibeiner* and *Vierbeiner*, meaning a two-legged or a four-legged being/creature. That of course, does make the distinction between a human and an animal. Even though there are rare animals that seem to be able to walk upright (e.g., kangaroos, monkeys, koala bears) in the German language a "two-legged creature" is almost always a complicated way of saying "human," so that word lends itself very easily to making the distinction between a human and an animal. Translated into French, the two-legged or four-legged creature becomes *bipède* ("two-footed being") and *quadrupède* ("four-footed being") respectively.

So the term "living creature" encompasses humans, animals and plants. (in the strict biology sence it even encompasses bacteria because they have cells and do pro-create it excludes virusses because they not not have cells and can not digest or pro-create themselves without the use of a host cell)

The term "created creature" can also mean robots or engineered viruses.

The label "breathing creature" applies only to humans and animals.

"Walking creature" could again include mobile robots.

"Living thing" labels humans, animals, plants, but also viruses and bacteria well, because they all live and change.

It is very typical for the English language to have a discussion abouth wheater or not humans are the result of evolution or are created by God. In most European languages there is no confussion about that.

In the German language for example, the word *Kreatur* is often used to imply that a human has an unpleasant character or that we are looking at something that is alive but we are totally uncertain as to the origin of the thing we've called "*Kreatur*". Therefore that particular word lends itself to all sorts of creatures or beasts or monsters from the literatue of science fiction.  Something like Frankenstein's monster would, for example, be called a *Kreatur* but not a human.

I would strongly advise that you look up all sorts of words on Google translate and try to find something in another language that describes exactly what are you are looking for.  You could easily introduce a foreign word in your game to describe a "breathing two- or four-legged being"

So what you are looking for is a word that describes the ability to move and breathe.

The word *Lebewesen* as I rembember it from biology lessons, means anything that is alive and breathes and has the ability to pro-create (even plants have that) but excludes viruses because in order to be considered a "living being" it needs to have at least one cell. Monocellular life forms are supposed to be the very first stage of life in the "evolution soup" theory of abiogenesis.  To create the simplest of cells requires, among other things, a minimum of 20 different types of proteins, oxygen, and electricity.

Viruses do not have any cells. Bacteria do have cells.

P.S.
Flora is is the goddess of flowering plants, and "fauna" refers to animals specifically of a certain time or region. "Flora" and "fauna" therefore means plants and animals and leaves out humans. Furthermore "flora" and "fauna" are understood to be plant and animal life in English, German, French and Dutch. It is not at all a way to describe humans but excludes them.

Comment: @Nikita I urge you to correct several errors:  the word "creature" is used by English-speaking biologists and creationists alike.  Monocellular life forms were not the first type of life postulated by theories of abiogenesis.  The smallest bacterium codes for almost 500 proteins, not 20.   Some thermophiles do not need oxygen but use sulfur instead.  "Fauna" is a collective term for animals, not plants.  Viruses cannot procreate independently, but bacteria do.  None of this has to do with English usage, so you may omit these comments, but if you keep them, make sure they're right.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in MMO programming terms, you have a MOB, short for MObile OBject, but that includes robots, ghosts, and zombies.

Comment: I have heard "monster object" or "monster or beast" but not "mobile object". Apparently the original use has been eclipsed by its backronyms.

Answer (score 2):

A real difficulty with this question is the gradual grading of "animals" *per se* into things that are "animal-ish" (to coin a word), especially since the boundary has been shifting back and forth quite a bit recently due to advances in gene sequencing technology. Little creepy-crawlies like choanoflagellates and *[Ministeria vibrans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministeria_vibrans)* are really muddying the water.

That said, try **metazoans**

> [Metazoan](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/metazoan): Any of numerous heterotrophic eukaryotic organisms of the kingdom Metazoa, characteristically having a multicellular body with cells differentiated into tissues; an animal.

Answer (score 1):

**[Mammals](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/mammal)**?

> any animal that gives birth to live babies, not eggs, and feeds its young on milk. Cows, humans and whales are all mammals. (Oxford)

By animal, I'm assuming you mean what we commonly call [animals](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/animal)

> *1.2* A mammal, as opposed to a bird, reptile, fish, or insect:

Comment: Not all animals are mammals though, e.g., lizard, birds etc.

Comment: @Jascol: See edit.

Comment: I don't think it's common to exclude birds, reptiles, and fish from the term *animal*.

Comment: Interesting, I've never used it in terms of sense 1.2. Perhaps this is an older, more archaic meaning and the term has undergone a semantic broadening over time?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/618962/2085).

Comment: @S.Buda: Do you have any references?

Comment: @library Nope, I don't know what I was thinking with that comment. It was almost 10 years ago though, so blame it on being young and dumb...

Answer (score 1):

Speaking as a programmer, if you might later add "spirits", "monsters", "undead" to this list *alongside* "human" and "(other) animal", then you do *not* want to start with a word that means "animals, including humans". You'll have to change it the first time you add anything. Rather, the heading should be **type of antagonist**, or **enemy type**, or something like that, since that's what this part of the form is for.

Speaking as a user of fantasy fiction, if you're building a hierarchy, and you want a category that includes both "humans" and "other animals" as sub-categories, then in future you'll add more categories *outside* and potentially inside this category, then perhaps call it **mundane**, to contrast with your supernatural monsters, undead, demons, and whatnot.

There's some potential quibbling in your future: plants aren't animals. But mundane plants usually also don't constitute an "encounter" in a game, so that might be OK. So, should plant antagonists be considered "mundane", and do you want them in this category alongside "humans", or elsewhere? If the answers to those questions don't match then "mundane" is no good, but if you're willing to put plants alongside animals in this category then you're OK, and if you're willing to consider any plant worthy of an "encounter" to be magical then you're also OK.

Other possible quibble: wizards are humans but they aren't mundane. You'd be relying on your users to understand that your hierarchy relates only to the species of the beings involved in the encounter, and that human is a "mundane species" even though some humans are magical.

Furthermore, a common word in fantasy for "animal, excluding humans" is **beast**. Since you're worried about the whole business of whether humans are considered animals or not, it might be best not to use the word "animal" anywhere in the taxonomy.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to remember that this problem is by no means special. The English language, just like most if not all languages, is full of examples where a larger category includes a special subcategory that is sometimes considered as such and sometimes as an opposite. Some examples:

- Technically, humans are clearly animals, but when a hunter says that before shooting he wants to go sure it's an animal moving in the bush, then we can assume he is contrasting *animal* with *human*.
- According to current biological definitions, mushrooms are not plants. But in general language this is not so clear. If collecting wild plants is forbidden somewhere, it's safe to assume you will get into trouble when you collect mushrooms. On the other hand, if you ask a child whether a drawing represents a plant, you might well get the response: "No, it's a mushroom."
- The meat of fish is not meat but fish, though no doubt some regulations concerning meat will include fish. (A very notable one doesn't: For the purposes of Catholic fasting on Fridays, fish is famously not included in meat.)
- An armchair is a kind of chair, but if you asked for a chair so you can reach the ceiling and remove a spider web, you won't appreciate being brought an armchair: "Didn't I say I want a *chair*? Did I mention an armchair?"
- A dog house and a doll house are of course houses; but if they are all the houses you own, don't be surprised to be called a liar when you claim to own houses.
- Speaking of liars: Technically, a single lie makes one a liar in context. It takes children a while to learn that it is not wise to use that technical definition with their parents because the term is usually reserved to people who lie in situations in which they can't get away with it.
- A lorry (for Americans: a truck) is probably a car when a sign says "no cars allowed beyond this point". If the sign says "only cars allowed beyond this point", it depends on the context. If it's the start of a motorway, lorries will be excluded; if it's a tiny private access road, the point of the sign is probably to forbid lorries as opposed to cars (while cyclists and pedestrians are still OK).
- A helicopter is an aircraft but not a plane. Here we are lucky to have two very clear terms for the larger category, one including helicopters and one not. Some other languages such as German are not so lucky. (German *Flugzeug* translates literally as *aircraft*, but since there is no separate German word for *aeroplane*, it can also be used to contrast with *Helikopter*.)
- "All free men are created equal", but does this include women? Apparently the people who put this into the Declaration of Independence didn't even think of them in this context. The hypocrisy of restricting this statement to free men bothered them enough to remove the word *free* before the final version, but not enough to include the anti-slavery passage or free their slaves. So it's not clear at all whether *men* in "All men are created equal" includes women and/or male slaves, let alone female slaves. Or children, for that matter.
- Torture is not torture when it is called enhanced interrogation and committed in the name of a country which can never be wrong.
- There are three kinds of sound: sound, ultrasound and infrasound.
- There are even more kinds of light. Besides light, infrared and ultraviolet there are also frequencies far away from the visible spectrum. Gamma-rays and X-rays, for example, while technically ultraviolet, would not normally be referred to as such. So *light* can refer to just visible light, to electromagnetic radiation close to the visible spectrum, or to all electromagnetic radiation.
- Sometimes it gets totally weird. *State* and *country* are usually synonyms, but in some cases only one word is usually applied to a large, sovereign entity, and the other to its smaller, non-sovereign constituents. E.g. the US is a country consisting of states and the UK is a state consisting of countries.
- Another weirdness: There are doctors (i.e. medical practitioners) who are not doctors (i.e. holders of a doctorate degree), and conversely there are doctors (i.e. holders of a doctorate degree) who are not doctors (i.e. medical practitioners). This is special in that there isn't even a proper general term for the two kinds of doctors.

A general solution for dealing with this kind of problem could use the technique shown in the following example:

> #### Animal
>
> - [ ] Human
> - [ ] Other intelligent animal capable of speech
> - [ ] Other animal.

Answer (score -1):

Life form. Includes goblins and plants, excludes undead, golems, elementals, robots, demons.

Comment: I think the inclusion of plants (and fungi and bacteria) might be the problem with this answer)

Comment: @Avon The question does not demand that plants be excluded, on the contrary, its context indicates that they should be included. I think your downvote is gratuitous. This is not the sort of answer that deserves punishment.

Comment: "animals, including humans" does explicitly exclude plants and other kingdoms - they are not animals.

Comment: @avon That is not what "explicitly" means. You believe that the question *implicitly* differentiates "animals, including humans" from plants, but the context *explicitly* says that "animals, including humans" is being differentiated from `(e.g. spirits, monsters, undead)`.

Comment: No I think it is explicit because animals explicitly do not mean plants. Animals (including humans) are life forms but there are plenty of good answers here that don't require leaping to catchall term that is little better than "things". Some other answers do and I've down voted them too. It's just a down vote. It's no big deal. It's not a punishment.

Comment: The down vote just means that I don't think this answer useful and I honestly don't. I think it's incorrect in that it doesn't mean "animals including humans" and unnecessary because there are plenty of better answers already. It's not a punishment. It's a vote. Explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

Here is something else that I found on the Internet that I think can help you to find the right word to use for your game:

This is taken from 
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/human+being

human being - any living or extinct member of the family Hominidae characterized by superior intelligence, articulate speech, and erect carriage

human, homo, man

lumbus, loin - either side of the backbone between the hipbone and the ribs in humans as well as quadrupeds

human beings, human race, humankind, humans, mankind, humanity, world, man - all of the living human inhabitants of the earth;

Homo erectus - extinct species of primitive hominid with upright stature but small brain; "Homo erectus was formerly called Pithecanthropus erectus"

Homo soloensis - extinct primitive hominid of late Pleistocene; Java; formerly Javanthropus

Homo habilis - extinct species of upright East African hominid having some advanced humanlike characteristics

Homo sapiens - the only surviving hominid; species to which modern man belongs; bipedal primate having language and ability to make and use complex tools; brain volume at least 1400 cc

Homo sapiens neanderthalensis, Neandertal, Neandertal man, Neanderthal, Neanderthal man - extinct robust human of Middle Paleolithic in Europe and western Asia

body, organic structure, physical structure - the entire structure of an organism

chassis, bod, human body, material body, physical body, physique, build, anatomy, figure, flesh, frame, shape, soma, form - alternative names for the body of a human being;

human being
human, man, woman, person, mortal,

A member of the human race:
being, body, creature, homo, human, individual, life, man, mortal, party, person, personage, soul.

quad·ru·ped:
A four-footed animal.
An animal, esp a mammal, that has all four limbs specialized for walking,having four feet

tetrapod - a vertebrate animal having four feet or legs or leglike appendages

an·i·mal
1. 
Any of numerous multicellular eukaryotic organisms of the kingdom Metazoa (or Animalia) that ingest food rather than manufacturing it themselves and are usually able to move about during at least part of their life cycle. Sponges, jellyfishes, flatworms, mollusks, arthropods, and vertebrates are animals.

2. An animal organism other than a human, especially a mammal.
3. A person who behaves in a bestial or brutish manner.
4. A human considered with respect to his or her physical nature, as opposed to rational or spiritual nature.
5. A person having a specified aptitude or set of interests: "that rarest of musical animals, an instrumentalist ......"

adj.

1. Relating to, characteristic of, or derived from an animal or animals, especially when not human: animal cells; animal welfare.
2. Relating to the physical as distinct from the rational or spiritual nature of people: animal instincts and desires.

animal 
1. (Zoology) zoology any living organism characterized by voluntary movement, the possession of cells with noncellulose cell walls and specialized sense organs enabling rapid response to stimuli, and the ingestion of complex organic substances such as plants and other animals.
2. any mammal, esp any mammal except man
3. a brutish person

an•i•mal

1. any member of the kingdom Animalia, comprising multicellular organisms that have a well-defined shape and usu. limited growth, can move voluntarily, actively acquire food and digest it internally, and have sensory and nervous systems that allow them to respond rapidly to stimuli.
2. any such living thing other than a human being.
3. a mammal, as opposed to a fish, bird, etc.
4. the physical or carnal nature of human beings; animality.
5. an inhuman person; brutish or beastlike person.

an·i·mal (ăn′ə-məl)

Any of a wide variety of multicellular organisms, most of which have a digestive tract, a nervous system, the ability to move voluntarily, and specialized sensory organs for recognizing and responding to their environment. Animals cannot manufacture their own food and must feed on plants, other animals, or other organic matter. Animals are grouped as a separate kingdom in taxonomy.

---

I guess describing your game figures as:

"multicellular organisms which have a digestive tract and nervous system and who tend to move around while very often feeding on meat and having the ability to make noise"

...is a very correct describtion for both humans and animals but to describe figures in a game, it sounds rather long and complicated  - lol :)

Answer (score -1):

Creatures that are alive - move - breath- feed themselves and procreate plus digest and have multiple cells - plus multiple legs.

That includes animals and humans - excludes plants, virusses, bacteria, funghi.

It also excludes, the monsters, ghosts, zombies, undead, spirits ect.

How about this:

Category 1 - the animal and human combination

Alive, breathing and consisting of flesh, bone and water for humans and animals, do bleed when injured, ability to feel and "remember" or learn from experience

Category 2 Phantasy figures:

Goblins, elfs, witches, gnoms, pac men, kobalds, snow white, dwarfs, Rumpelstilzchen, speaking animals

Category 3 SF figures:

Alien, Predator, Terminator, Marsians, little green men, area 51 subjects

Category 4 Scary monsters:

Frankenstein, Godzilla, Chucky, Terminator

Category 5 the undead:

Ghosts, zombies, spirits, poltergeists, werwolfs, vampires

Category 6 Superheros:
Superman, Electra, the Green Lantern, Mutant X, the Avengers,